# scalaz-stream tcp `echo` app not work

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I write an echo app that `send` and `receive` `'\0'` terminated string

https://gist.github.com/jilen/10a664cd588af10b7d09

```
object Foo {

  implicit val S = scalaz.concurrent.Strategy.DefaultStrategy
  implicit val AG = tcp.DefaultAsynchronousChannelGroup
  ...

  def runServer() {
    def writeStr(str: String) = tcp.write(ByteVector(str.getBytes))
    val echoServer = (readStr |> serverLog("[Server] Receiving")).flatMap(writeStr)
    val server = tcp.server(addr, concurrentRequests = 1)(echoServer.repeat)
    server.flatMap(_.drain).run.run
  }

  def runClient() {
    val topic = async.topic[String]()
    val echoClient = (topic.subscribe |> clientLog("[Client] Inputing")).map { str =>
      tcp.write(ByteVector(str.getBytes) ++ Delimiter) ++ (readStr |> clientLog("[Client] Receiving"))
    }
    val client = tcp.connect(addr)(tcp.lift(echoClient))
    client.run.runAsync(println)
    io.stdInLines.to(topic.publish).run.run
  }
}
```

I run `Foo.runServer()` and `Foo.runClient()` on different terminal

And enter numbers *1 2 3 ...* from the client console, but client receive no reply.

[image]
[image]

What's wrong with my echo app ?

Comment: what is the type of Server? its a `Process[Task, Process[Task, Throwable \/ A]]]` right?  So `server.run.run` is a `Process[Task, Throwable \/ A]` which you throw away, right?

Comment: @stew How can I run the server ?

Comment: Am I right about the types? if so then it seems like you should be running the process instead of throwing it away.

Comment: or can you provide a full working example to play with?

Comment: @stew look at the gist link, that's the full code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I rewrite the client as

```
val echoClient = tcp.subscribe.map(str => ByteVector(str.getBytes) ++ Delimiter)

val client = tcp.connect(addr)(tcp.writes(echoClient))
```

And it works